# Markdown editor that opens local files from relative links

Tags: open-source, markdown, wiki, editor, debian

I usually maintain notes with [Zim Desktop Wiki](http://zim-wiki.org). It has a wiki-like GUI (with hyperlinks), and behind the scenes stores text files in a folder. It has it's own markup language.

I'm looking for a similar tool that specifically stores files in Markdown (or CommonMark) format. So it should:

- have a free/libre/open license
- be packaged for Debian (or can otherwise be installed on Debian)
- read and write to Markdown (preferably CommonMark)
- have an editing GUI
- when the user clicks on a relative link, open the local file corresponding to that link

It would ideally:

- support project wikis (as found on GitHub, GitLab, Gogs and Gitea)

It does not have to implement:

- formatting toolbar
- convert markup to visual layout (plain text with links is fine)
- markup language other than Markdown/CommonMark

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net).

- Items are stored as plain text, (and archived as zip files).
- have a free/libre/open license **Free, Gratis & Open Source**
- be packaged for Debian (or can otherwise be installed on Debian) **Cross Platform including Linux**
- read and write to Markdown (preferably CommonMark) **Uses a variant of markdown**
- have an editing GUI **Yes & a display one**
- when the user clicks on a relative link, open the local file corresponding to that link **Opens both local files & URLs with the default association**
- Spell Checking
- Embed Pictures
- Multiple Languages
- Export to a number of formats.

Screenshot Editing Mode (Win 10)
[image]

Screenshot Display Mode (Win 10)
[image]

Comment: it looks like this uses txt2tags for markup, I'll test it against some markdown files